# Nested namespaces

Tags: c#

I've got something like this:

```csharp
namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        class foo{}
    }
}
```

In other file I write:

```csharp
using n1;
```

Why I can't type now something like:

```csharp
n2.foo smthing;
```

And how to make something like this possibile?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [namespace aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

```
using n2 = n1.n2;

...
n2.foo something;
```

What is before the class name should be a complete name space (with/or other class name(s) for nested types). A truncated namespace will not work.

Answer (score 36):

This is a deliberate rule of C#. If you do this:

```
namespace Frobozz
{
    namespace Magic
    {
        class Lamp {}
    }

    class Foo
    {
        Magic.Lamp myLamp; // Legal; Magic means Frobozz.Magic when inside Frobozz
    }
}
```

That is legal. But this is not:

```
namespace Frobozz
{
    namespace Magic
    {
        class Lamp {}
    }
}

namespace Flathead
{
    using Frobozz;
    class Bar
    {
        Magic.Lamp myLamp; // Illegal; merely using Frobozz does not bring Magic into scope
    }
}
```

The rule of C# that describes this is in section 7.6.2 of the C# 4 spec. This is a very confusing section; the bit you want is the paragraph near the end that says

> Otherwise, if the namespaces imported by the using-namespace-directives of the namespace declaration contain exactly one type having name I...

The key point is that it says "exactly one type", not "exactly one type **or namespace**".  We deliberately disallow you "slicing" a namespace name like this *when you are outside of that namespace* because it is potentially confusing.  As others have said, if you want to do that sort of thing, fully qualify it once in a using-alias directive and then use the alias.

Comment: Quite late here, but... Can I use this namespace scoping to DEFINE nested namespaces without the need to use fully qualified names for the new namespaces? That would ease things a lot, avoiding duplicated and typo-prone typing...

Comment: @heltonbiker: That sounds like a great question for StackOverflow... which is the site you're already on. Post a question!

Comment: Well, your're right. Interestingly, I tried it and it works. Unfortunately, namespaces only appear in the Class View panel of Visual Studio if they have something (a class, for example) defined inside them. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Why is this answer not accepted? The accepted one looks irrelevant to what's being asked in this topic.

Comment: @wEight: The accepted answer is chosen by the user who asked the question. I know this might seem strange, but many times people ask questions which are only tangentially related to the problem they really have.

Comment: @EricLippert It is misleading. Thankfully there are answers related to other questions, but having a title refactor proposal for such threads would always be welcome.

Answer (score 11):

By design, [`namespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx) are there to help you define scope.

Unless you fully qualify it, you will get the error you're seeing.

Assuming File1 has something like this:

```
namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        class Foo { }
    }
}
```

You can do this two ways:

### Fully qualified `using`

File2 contents:

```
namespace n3
{
    using n1.n2;

    class TestClass
    {
        private Foo something;
    }
}
```

### Use a [`namespace alias`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
namespace n3
{
    using n2 = n1.n2;

    class TestClass
    {
        private n2.Foo something;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Section 9.4.2 paragraph 4 in the C# language specification explains this behavior explicitly:

> A *using-namespace-directive* imports
>   the types contained in the given
>   namespace, but specifically does not
>   import nested namespaces.

It even goes on to give an example that is very similar to your own.

```
namespace N1.N2
{
    class A {}
}
namespace N3
{
    using N1;
    class B: N2.A {}        // Error, N2 unknown
}
```

Of course had you done this:

```
namespace n1
{
  public class Example
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      n2.Foo a; // This is legal.
    }
  }
}
```

This would compile because `n2` is accessible since it is referenced from within an ancestor namespace block.

Comment: What's the reason for that rule?

Comment: @Ini When you think about it, allowing such namespace cascading would defeat one of the primary purposes of using namespaces, which is preventing name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write this, as `n2` is inside of `n1`. If you want to access the `n2` namespace, you can try typing `using n2 = n1.n2` at the beginning of your other file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to declare your nested namespace as class.

You can have:

```cs
namespace NS1
{
    public class NNS1
    {
        public class C { }
    }
}
namespace NS2
{
    public class NNS2
    {
        public class C { }
    }
}
```

Then use your namespaces by:

```cs
using NS1;
using NS2;

class C
{
    public C()
    {
        var c1 = new NNS1.C();
        var c2 = new NNS2.C();
    }
}
```

However, this cannot create union of namespaces. If you have:

```cs
namespace NS1
{
    public class NNS
    {
        public class C1 { }
    }
}
namespace NS2
{
    public class NNS
    {
        public class C2 { }
    }
}
```

And

```cs
using NS1;
using NS2;

class C
{
    public C()
    {
        var c1 = new NNS.C1();
        var c2 = new NNS.C2();
    }
}
```

The compiler will complain about `NNS` for ambiguity, since it can refer to two class symbol in this context. I have tried to declare namespaces as interfaces, and use a class to implement them for creating union of namespaces. However, implementing an interface does not automatically import nested classes symbols in it.

I do not know why C# does not support reference of nested namespace, and I have no idea about the drawbacks for declaring namespaces as classes. Please comment if anyone knows.