# Using using with nested namespaces

Tags: c#

Is there any reason, why

```
new N1.N2.N3.C();
```

would compile, but

```
using N1.N2;
...
new N3.C();
```

would not?

**EDIT**

Class C is defined in another referenced assembly like this:

```
namespace N1.N2.N3
{
   class C
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because namespaces need to be either fully qualified in their use or via a using. An object's definition either has a fully qualified namespace, an alias or nothing - in which case the full namespace must have a using.

`N3` is not a full namespace - it's just a part of one.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I got confused because N3.C works fine from within N1.N2.SomeOtherNamespace. So the statement is not completely correct, in some cases you can also use only partial namespace names.

Comment: The rule is that you can use N3.C from _within_ the N1.N2 namespace(as in the case of N1.N2.SomeOtherNameSpace) but **not** from _another_ namespace. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297279/nested-namespaces) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Because you arent including the N3 namespace, thus C isnt found.

Comment: Its a whole new namespace, you include only N2 not each namespace in it. If it werent that way, you could just add `using System` to include the whole .net framework!

Comment: Your comment isn't relevant _TJHeuvel_. _Bohdan_ didn't ask why `N3.C()` won't compile when only `using N1` is specified but when `using N1.N2` is. It's just a one-level reference. You can't compare it with "`using System` _to include the whole .net framework_" as you said.

Comment: But in N2 you could have N2a and N2b with C class. So one level reference doesnt make sense too.