# What is the difference between namespace dot namespace and nested namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Is there any difference between:

```
namespace Outer.Inner
{
}
```

And

```
namespace Outer
{
    namespace Inner
    {
    }
}
```

in C#?

Comment: In my experience however the first option is cleaner and eliminates multiple layers of nesting. This can be very helpful for clarity in others reading your code, but as such is the freedom of code. Use wisely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference whatsoever, those are the same thing, however the first one is more common.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you don't put any other declarations or `using` directives in the `Outer` namespace, there's no difference at all.

Given that you would very *very* rarely declare members in multiple namespaces within a single file, I'd suggest using the first form - aside from anything else it saves a level of indentation. Note that "brace at the start of a new line" is a more conventional bracing style for C# though:

```
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been programming in C++ for a while now and I really don't like braces at the start of new lines, I don't know why, but it's very hard for me to read code like that!

Comment: @paul: While the bracing convention isn't as universal as naming, I think it's worth trying to immerse yourself in the most common conventions of the language - you'll get used to it pretty quickly, and then all the examples etc that you'll read on the net will be easier to read... *and* anyone reading your code (from a C# background) will find it easier to read.

Comment: thanks, I will try to do that from now on, however I have seen some libraries on this website: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ use the same style of bracing as i use, but I guess you are right, thanks for the tips!

Comment: @paul: There are all kinds of conventions in there that I would hesitate to recommend ;)

Answer (score 7):

No, but the first variant is the most used in c# code.
The second variant is what you'd have to write in C++ and I'm not sure I ever saw it in real c# code yet.

Answer (score 2):

They both are the same as noted by other answers and per documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces).

Also the fact the one namespace is defined inside another doesn't really mean that it has any special relationship with the parent or that it brings any particular features in relation with parent or that it depends on parent namespace. There is no relationship other than it's just defined inside parent (in context of `using` statement to bring them in).

As such, it is important to note that if you include the parent namespace, it doesn't meant the child names are now accessible. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297795/841330) answer which explains this.

So despite the fact they are nested, for all practically purposes, each namespace is its own independent thing, no matter if its the top most parent or a child. You will `always` need to use fully qualified name of the nested namespace if you want to include it.

As such the dot(.) almost becomes part of the namespace much like you can have a gmail id as first.last@gmail.com

**So why nested?**

It really is just to logically place them as if they are in a hierarchy for benefit of organizing them but you can think of the dot in the name as part of the namespace (for all practical uses).

for example you can define this:

```
namespace Outer.Inner
{
   class MyClass{}
}
```

But if you wanted, you can rename the above to the following for all practical purposes:

```
namespace Solar
{
   class MyClass{}
}
```

In both cases if you want to use `MyClass`, you will need to include fully qualified name of the namespace where the class is defined which is:

```
using Outer.Inner;
```

or

```
using Solar;
```

This can best be understood and summarized in looking at C# library namespaces.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

So although, the above three lines contain nested namespaces, each line really is fully qualified name to a unique namespace (as if the dot is part of the namespace) and that should be useful to know in terms of the differences and usage.