# How to access to root namespace in debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, namespaces, breakpoints

How to access to root namespace in **debug** while we are inside the namespace with **duplicated** name?

For example:

**Root namespace:** *Project*

**Namespace which caught a breakpoint:** *Project*.Models.*Project* (notice duplicated Project segment).

**Code:**

```
using Project.Models.Project;

namespace Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Foo().Bar();
        }
    }

    namespace Models
    {
        namespace Project
        {
            public class Foo
            {
                public void Bar()
                {
                     //breakpoint! in this moment I want to access to Bar class (there is no `using Project.Models.Issue;` above)
                     //var boo = new Boo(); Cannot resolve symbol 'Boo'
                }
            }
        }

        namespace Issue
        {
            public class Boo { }
        }
    }
}
```

**Watch window:**

[image: watch window]

There is access only to nested *Project* namespace (*Project.Models.Project*), but I'm not able to access to the root namespace with the same name and go to *Project.Models.Issues.Boo*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  the global namespace alias (`global::`) to indicate that you want to start from the root namespace:

```
var boo = new global::Project.Models.Issues.Boo()
```

As @rory.ap has correctly pointed out, in this case you can do without the global namespace alias, but sometimes it is your only choice. Consider this example:

```
namespace Foo {
    class Bar {}
    namespace Bat {
        namespace Foo {
            class Bar {}
        }
        static class Test {
            public static void AccessNS() {
                //The global:: alias is necessary here to avoid a creating a Foo.Bat.Foo.Bar()
                var fooBar = new global::Foo.Bar();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var boo = new Models.Issue.Boo();
```

The compiler is slightly confused because of the multiple `Project` namespaces, but within that scope, you only need to qualify it starting with the `Models` namespace.

The other thing you could do to help the compiler discern between the different `Project` namespaces is utilize an alias to `Project` in your `using` directive:

```
using Project.Models.Project;
using p = Project;
```

Then this will work:

```
var boo = new p.Models.Issue.Boo();
```

Yet another perfectly good option is provided by Sefe's answer.

Comment: Not duplicated, but related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-statements-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace

Comment: btw, same problem of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297279/nested-namespaces

Comment: @rory.ap yeah I know how to fix that, but I was curious how to access to this namespace when I'm in debug and don't want to cancel it and modify code. Both solutions are great ;)

Comment: @Pawel Maga, I also test it in my side, without using the custom code, it is really hard to view or access the root namespace in debugging directly. So I think Sefe and rory.ap provided the correct answer for this issue. If possible, you could mark it as the answer. In addition, if you have good suggestion, you could submit the uservoice to the product team here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio.