# How to access nested namespaces to avoid the need to fully qualify in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but this issue has dogged me for some time.

I define some classes in a couple of different nested namespaces:

```
namespace Awesome.Example {

    namespace V1 {
        public class PopTart {
            public bool PoppinUp {get; set;}
            public bool Hot {get; set;}
        }
    }

    namespace V2 {
        public class PopTart {
            public bool PoppinUp {get; set;}
            public bool SoCool {get; set;}
            public bool AreHot {get; set;}
        }
    }

}
```

But if I try to simplify declaration with includes, the IDE (VS) complains that I need to fully qualify the classes.

For Example:

```
using Awesome.Example;

public class Main {

    public V1.PopTart Strawberry {get; set;}
    public V2.PopTart Blueberry  {get; set;}

}
```

This produces two errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'V1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'V2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I don't understand why this is.  Can anyone explain how to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: Please specify the property name:  public `V1.PopTart PROPERTY_NAME {get; set;}`

Comment: You can't do that. That partial namespace thing like `V1.PopTart` will work if `Main` is defined in `Awesome.Example`, or a `Main` in `Awesome` could declare `public Example.V1.PopTart A { get; set; }`. But `Main` has to have some common "ancestor" namespace with those classes. Otherwise, it has to be all or nothing. This may be to keep name resolution more manageable.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies things considerably.  I wasn't aware the common ancestor was necessary.  I had assumed that providing the "using" would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using namespace aliases like so:

```
using V1 = Awesome.Example.V1;
using V2 = Awesome.Example.V2;

public class Main
{
    public V1.PopTart p1 { get; set; }
    public V2.PopTart p2 { get; set; }

}
```

Or fully qualify your namespace like so:

```
public class Main
{
    public Awesome.Example.V1.PopTart p1 { get; set; }
    public Awesome.Example.V2.PopTart p2 { get; set; }
}
```

For further explanation and examples refer to the following question: [Nested namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297279/nested-namespaces)

Comment: Excellent summary in the question you linked to.  Didn't come up in my searches.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full namespace with nested namespace like

```
public class Main
{
    public Awesome.Example.V1.PopTart var1{get; set;}
    public Awesome.Example.V2.PopTart var2{get; set;}
}
```