# When importing namespace compiler returns error message type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, namespaces

When I'm trying to import a namespace from another file, the compiler gives me the error message, "type or namespace name could not be found". Take a look at my code below. Both files are in the same directory, so I don't understand what's wrong.

Setup.cs (the main file)

```
using System;
using ScreenTextLine; // Error is here.

namespace Setup 
{
    namespace Screen 
    {
        class Text 
        {
            static void Main(string[] args) {  }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem.cs (the file with the namespace I'm trying to import)

```
using System;
namespace Setup 
{
    namespace ScreenTextLine
    {
        class WelcomeText 
        {
            static void Main(string[] args){}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with compiler. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297279/nested-namespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use their fully-qualified name when referencing them by separating each namespace by a dot using the following format...

[Top_level_namespace].[nested_namespace]

So, this nested structure...

```
namespace Setup
{
    namespace Screen
    {
    }
}
```

It's referenced by a `using` statement this way...

```
using Setup.Screen;
```

Comment: Now it gives the error message "Setup.cs(2,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ScreenTextLine' does not exist in the namespace 'Setup' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I would highly appreciate it if you gave me an example of both files, but revised to work.

Comment: You're probably referencing the wrong namespaces!. Add `using Setup.ScreenTextLine;` to Setup.cs and then `using Setup.Screen;` to the other code file (Problem.cs)

Comment: Weird. It's still returns the same error. Maybe it's a .NET framework compatibility issue? My computer says it downloaded the 2019 release of the framework (version 4.8)

Comment: Sorry but I'm not in front of the computer at the moment to test that. Make those class `public`. They are `private` at the moment and the compiler is probably not generating any namespace for them

Comment: I made all the classes in all files public by adding the public keyword before them, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure? Is this a console app? If so, you can only have ONE entry point in a console app. This line is an entry point `static void Main(string[] args) { }` and you can only have one specified

Comment: It indeed is a console app. But, if I only specify one entry point, the other file won't work.

Comment: I'll repeat...you can only have ONE entry point in a console app. I can't make it any clearer than that. Sorry

Comment: I changed a few things up, and it worked! Thanks for the answer!!